# Azure DevOps Repo restrict Git Commit to specific folders

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

In the Azure DevOps repo, I would like to allow git commits into a particular folder alone. If the developer commits to any other folder in a git repo, I would like the git commit to be rejected. Is it possible with Azure DevOps?

Let's say a repo contains 3 folders `folder1`, `folder2`, and `folder3` and I would like to allow a developer to commit only to `folder2` only. Is it possible with the Azure DevOps repo?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the [File Path Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/repository-settings?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#file-path-validation-policy) policy. You can define a path, or a wildcard pattern, or a set of paths and patterns, and Azure DevOps will block the pushes if one of those paths is present in a commit.

Note, however, that you can't set this policy per developer - it's done per repository for all participants. If you need to configure something similar per developer, then you should look into the [Status Checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#require-approval-from-external-services) and the Status API.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict creating new folders in a specific level?

Folder0
Folder1
   - Folder1.1
   - Folder1.2

I don't want anyone to add any new folders on Folder1.. but they can add anything under existing folders

Comment: I think it doesn't differentiate a folder creation or any other change in that path. I would say that if you deny the push into some path, it means any kind of push, including the folder creation.